# extracting all iframe-tags using htmlagilitypack

Tags: c#, html, html-agility-pack

I'm using htmlagilitypack to extract several html-tags. Heres what I do:

```
        HtmlDoc = new HtmlDocument();
        StringReader sr = new StringReader(decodedHTML);
        HtmlDoc.Load(sr);
        sr.close();
        var anchor_tags = HtmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//" + HTML.TAG_ANCHOR + "[@" + HTML.ATTRIBUT_HREF + "]");
        var embed_tags = HtmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//" + HTML.TAG_EMBED + "[@" + HTML.TAG_EMBED_SRC + "]");
        var iframe_tags = HtmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//" + HTML.TAG_IFRAME + "[@" + HTML.TAG_IFRAME_SRC + "]");
        var img_tags = HtmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//" + HTML.TAG_IMG + "[@" + HTML.TAG_IMG_SRC + "]");
        var audio_tags = HtmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//" + HTML.TAG_AUDIO);       // may contain inner-html
        var object_tags = HtmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//" + HTML.TAG_OBJECT);     // may contain inner-html
        var video_tags = HtmlDoc.DocumentNode.SelectNodes("//" + HTML.TAG_VIDEO);       // may contain inner-html
```

Where decodedHTML is the html-page packed in a string. After that I examine if the variables above are null

```
        if (anchor_tags != null)
        {
            ExtractLinks_AnchorTags(anchor_tags);
        }
        if(audio_tags != null)
        {
            ExtractLinks_AudioTags(audio_tags);
        }
        if(embed_tags!=null)
        {
            ExtractLinks_EmbedTags(embed_tags);
        }
        if (iframe_tags != null)
        {
            ExtractLinks_iFrameTags(iframe_tags);
        }
        if (img_tags != null)
        {
            ExtractLinks_ImgTags(img_tags);
        }
        if (object_tags != null)
        {
            ExtractLinks_ObjectTags(object_tags);
        }
        if (video_tags != null)
        {
            ExtractLinks_ObjectTags(video_tags);
        }
```

and some of them are definitly null, because most of the extractLinks-methods aren't even called. For example when I'm visiting y o u t u b e . c o m . There are several iframe-tags and the code doesnt recognize them.

edit:

when I'm deleting the
`"[@" + HTML.TAG_IFRAME_SRC + "]"` the iframes are recognized, but I just want to extract the iframes with a src attribute. What's the correct xpath syntax for it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HtmlAgilityPack does not load the contents of `iframe` elements.

In order to inspect the content of an `iframe`, read the `src` attribute (which represents the `iframe`'s URI) and perform a separate web request to load that into a separate `HtmlDocument`.

Along the way, be aware of these possible issues:

- the `src` attribute may contain a relative URI. For example, if you visit `http://www.example.com` and see that an `iframe` has `src="/samplePage"`, you should convert that first to an absolute URI (in this case, `http://www.example.com/samplePage`)
- it is possible that some `iframe` elements do not have a `src` tag, because it is added dynamically, via javascript, when the document is rendered in a browser. It is also possible to create entire `iframe` elements with javascript, elements that you wouldn't even see if you just do a regular `HttpWebRequest`. In cases like these, you have to analyze the javascript present on the page and to duplicate that logic in your program.

### Update

The XPath expression for `iframe` elements that have a `src` attribute is: `//iframe[@src]`

Comment: Thanks for that. Since I got no idea about javascript I wont be able to realize your second point. But the first one should be possible. However, I just want to extract the uri and the type (mime-type) of the content of an Iframe. Does the HtmlAgilityPack load the attributes of an IFrame?

Comment: @user1826831 yes, HtmlAgilityPack should load any attributes of the iframe element (unless they are dynamically added). I'm not sure you can find out the mime-type unless you do a request to that particular URI. It's theoretically possible for a URI like `http://example.com/test.jpg` to return content of type `text/plain`.

Comment: @user1826831 regarding javascript - I'm also not a javascript expert, but if I hack my way through a script I can usually find out what it's doing. Modern browsers usually have javascript debuggers which are very handy for such tasks.

Comment: the mimetype of an html-tag might be extractable either by the uri or by the "type"-attribute. Since iframe does not provide a type-attribute, the dataextension of the uri is the only way for me at the moment. How does the browser find out? (since he needs to, to interpret the given object) By the way, I'm only interested in html-elements containing images, audio or video.

Comment: If an <a> tag is containing an <img> tag, will the code above be able to detect it?

Comment: iframe tags usually contain html documents, so the content type should typically be text/html. There may be more complex logic built in the browser for detection of content type, but I don't know how it works.

Comment: tags of the form <a> <img /> <a/> are handled by HtmlAgilityPack like you would expect.